# Edit multiple lines and insert

Tags: insert-mode, visual-block

Say I have a text file:

```
abc
abc
abc
```

I want to change it to this:

```
adbc
adbc
adbc
```

My current way of doing this is to move the cursor to the `b` in the first (or last) line, select the column of `b`s with <kbd>Ctrl+v</kbd>, <kbd>2j</kbd> change it with <kbd>c</kbd> and type `d`.

But this means I also have to reenter the `b` which was deleted. It would be much nicer to *insert* at this point instead of *changing*, but <kbd>i</kbd> does not seem to work in visual block mode.

Is there a way of doing this – that is, without having to delete a character?

Comment: See here: https://vimhelp.org/visual.txt.html#v_b_I

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is: after selecting in visual mode, use <kbd>I</kbd> to insert before the selection, and use <kbd>A</kbd> to insert after it.

Thanks a lot @Christian Brabandt!